# why does spine.Model have functions with the same name in the prototype

Tags: javascript, spine.js

I am trying to understand how it works

Why do functions have the same name in the prototype and how are they being used if the function
 for example Model.fromForm takes precedence over the prototype one. I mean the declarations are made in the base class/object. What exactly is happening when you create a model from that base class/object?

Also I have another question but I will wait for this one first.

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spine model object and "instances" of the model are different objects, so different functions are evaluated. There is no precedence or overloading here. For example (in coffeescript) the following does the same thing:

```
YourModel instance = YourModel.fromForm(form) # Uses the model object fromForm
```

and

```
YourModel instance = new YourModel
instance.fromForm(form) # Uses the prototype fromForm
```

If you [look at the source code](https://github.com/spine/spine/blob/master/src/spine.coffee), you can see why it's equivalent; the object `fromForm` is simply declared as `this.fromForm`, and it calls the prototype one:

```
@fromForm: ->
  (new this).fromForm(arguments...)
```

Comment: thanks, that is helpfull..could you perhaps look at a symplified code example of a spine model..maybe you can spot where it is going wrong.I am am now working with firebug trying to figure out when "this" is what?..very confusing

Comment: You should just post your second question as a new question with code! Someone will be able to help.

Comment: yes I can do that, too bad because it's sort of related.. but I will because it bugs me..thank you